# Как обновить все поля id одним запросом?

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим есть таблица `articles` с полями `id,title,text`.
`id` это поле с автоинкрементом, но в этом поле значения идут не по порядку, а в разброс, к примеру 0,1,5,6,20,22.
Как одним запросом упорядочить это поле `id`, т.е. чтобы значения поля `id` были упорядочены, (0,1,2,3,4,5...)?

**P.S.** в данном случае не интересуют связи с этим полем `id` в других таблицах.
**P.S.**  это нужно в учебных целях.
Кстати случайно затёр поле `title` в этой же таблице.
т.е. в этом поле было название записи, теперь там стоит одинаковое число во всех записях 
**таблица `articles`**:
 (запись 1: [id=0;title=2;])
 (запись 2: [id=1;title=2;])
 (запись 3: [id=5;title=2;])
Как одним запросом поменять поле `title`, в данном случае не важно какое там будет значение, главное чтобы разное, к примеру `title1,title2,title3`.
Меня интересует как можно одним запросом поменять поле `id`, чтобы упорядочить его значения, и вторым запросом чтобы восстановить поле `title`, это в учебных целях нужно

Comment: А какой профит от этого действия?

Comment: @Сергей Мишин, это в учебных целях

Comment: На самом деле это ненужное действие, поэтому и ответы на самом деле тут неверные. Это так, к слову

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в БД нет понятия "идут подряд", в общем случае.
попробуйте вот так

```
SET @i:=0;
UPDATE articles SET id = @i:=(@i+1) WHERE 1=1;

update articles set title=concat('title', CAST(id as VARCHAR(50)));
```

Comment: по первому запросу(id) выдало такую ошибку: `#1062 - Дублирующаяся запись '1' по ключу 'PRIMARY'`, по второму(title) выдало такую: `#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'VARCHAR(50)))' на строке 1`.  Согласен, там возможно какая-то незначительная ошибка, но пока что не знаю как исправить

Comment: Если у вас первичный ключ на ID, то надо поставить как начальное значение максимальное значение ключа+1
а вторым шагом уже сбрасывать на 1,2,3

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: SET @i:=50000000;

Comment: а как исправить обновление поля `title`?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(25.65 AS varchar);` `#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'varchar)' на строке 1`

Comment: получается значение поля ID вещественное число?

Comment: та нет, `id - int(11), title - varchar(100)`

Comment: приведите пожалуйста ваш запрос, который выдает ошибку

Comment: попробуйте так

update articles set title=concat('title', CAST(id, CHAR));

Comment: `update articles set title=concat('title', CAST(id as char));`, да, этот запрос сработал, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Нет такой возможности, только в два этапы.

```
ALTER TABLE `articles` DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: благодарю, а подскажете по второму вопросу, он похож на первый, не хотел создавать новую тему, т.е. как обновить поле `title` в таблице `articles`? чтобы было title1,title2,title3, а сейчас в поле `title` стоит 2

Comment: Вам уже ответили по поводу тайтла, не успел)